# How to show 98th (or any custom) percenetile in jmeter html dashboard?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, percentile

I've been searching a lot but no luck so far, I need to change the default percentile metrics shown in jmeter html dashboards, depending on the project I need to analyze different SLAs, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made it, I tried the same before but I didn't see any change reflected in dashboard that time, but now I see the 98th percentile, only needed to add below lines to user.properties file in jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Aggregate Report and Aggregate Graph - configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Percentiles to display in reports
# Can be float value between 0 and 100
# First percentile to display, defaults to 90%
aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
# Second percentile to display, defaults to 95%
aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
# Second percentile to display, defaults to 99%
aggregate_rpt_pct3=98
```